# Change the style of particular cells of DataGridView in WinForms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm binding a DataGridView in my Windows Application with a DataTable. On the RowsAdded event of DataGridView i'm writing to code to change the style of particular cells.

I have tried following code for it, but its not working

```
Private Sub grdView_RowsAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles grdView.RowsAdded

        Dim f = New Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        For index As Integer = e.RowIndex To e.RowIndex + e.RowCount - 1
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = grdView.Rows(index)
            If Decimal.Parse(row.Cells("Variance Up").Value.ToString) >= Decimal.Parse(txtRise1.Text) Then
                row.Cells("Variance Up").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                row.Cells("Variance Up").Style.Font = f
            ElseIf Decimal.Parse(row.Cells("Variance Up").Value.ToString) >= Decimal.Parse(txtRise2.Text) Then
                row.Cells("Variance Up").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                row.Cells("Variance Up").Style.Font = f
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

What I want to do is as follows:

[image]

Comment: How doesn't it work? `it's not working` is too general. BTW, the `RowsAdded` event is not suitable unless your data is not changed after added.

Comment: @KingKing The problem is the RowsAdded event is getting fired four times on every grid bind

Comment: You don't need `c#` tag for this question.

Comment: @SonerGönül Answers in C# will also work for me.

Comment: @FarhanMukadam that's partly why `RowsAdded` is not suitable. Of course when you bind your grid, it will add rows for you (instead of doing manually) and the `RowsAdded` will be fired.

Comment: @KingKing So whats the solution? Which event should i use?

Comment: @FarhanMukadam maybe `RowPosPaint` or `CellValueChanged`

Comment: @KingKing ok ill try and reply.

Comment: @KingKing RowPostPaint works. Thank You.

Comment: @King - if you'd like to take credit for the wiki answer, please post an answer and leave a comment on the post. I will promptly delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered in the comments:

> [@FarhanMukadam that's partly why `RowsAdded` is not suitable. Of course when you bind your grid, it will add rows for you (instead of doing manually) and the `RowsAdded` will be fired.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653161/change-the-style-of-particular-cells-of-datagridview-in-winforms#comment27466999_18653161) – [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king)
>
> [@KingKing So whats the solution? Which event should i use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653161/change-the-style-of-particular-cells-of-datagridview-in-winforms#comment27467043_18653161) – [Farhan Mukadam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2594075/farhan-mukadam)
>
> [@FarhanMukadam maybe `RowPosPaint` or `CellValueChanged`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653161/change-the-style-of-particular-cells-of-datagridview-in-winforms#comment27467084_18653161) – [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king)
>
> [@KingKing RowPostPaint works. Thank You.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653161/change-the-style-of-particular-cells-of-datagridview-in-winforms#comment27467793_18653161) – [Farhan Mukadam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2594075/farhan-mukadam)

For further information about the `RowPostPaint` event, please see the MSDN documentation:

### [DataGridView.RowPostPaint Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowpostpaint.aspx)